Why am I getting a "SYNC_CREATE_CONTEXT_FAILED ERROR 20037" during data synchronization in my GridDB cluster?
I'm working on a distributed system where I need to synchronize data across a cluster of nodes. However, I'm encountering an error during the synchronization process. The error message I get is:
20037 SYNC_CREATE_CONTEXT_FAILED ERROR Data synchronization of cluster failed. Memory may be insufficient.
Insufficient memory may be one possible reason. Check if there is sufficient memory space in the system.
Here is a simplified version of the code that triggers the error:
import os
import psutil
from griddb_python import Container, GridStoreFactory, StoreFactory

def check_memory():
    memory_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
    print(f"Total memory: {memory_info.total}")
    print(f"Available memory: {memory_info.available}")
    return memory_info.available > 500 * 1024 * 1024  # Ensure at least 500MB is free

def sync_griddb_data():
    if not check_memory():
        raise MemoryError("Not enough memory available to start synchronization.")
    
    try:
        factory = StoreFactory.get_default()
        gridstore = factory.get_store({
            "host": "239.0.0.1",
            "port": 41999,
            "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        })
        container = gridstore.get_container("containerName")
        container.put_rows([
            {"id": 1, "value": "value1"},
            {"id": 2, "value": "value2"},
        ])
        print("Data synchronization successful.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Data synchronization failed: {e}")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sync_griddb_data()

My Questions:
What are the best practices to handle this kind of memory-intensive operation in a multi-threaded environment?
How can I ensure that there is sufficient memory before starting the synchronization process?
Are there any specific memory management techniques or tools in Python that can help prevent this error?
Is there a better approach to synchronize data across multiple nodes to avoid running into memory issues?
I'm currently utilizing a Ubuntu 22.04(x64), and my GridDB version is "5.3.1.
